# HP Mini won't work with battery alone without an AC power

Tags: power

What to do with HP Mini netbook that doesn't work without AC adapter? Even if the battery is attached and with 80%-up power charged. I consider that maybe need replacement and I did with the working battery from another netbook with the same model and brand.

Comment: Its an internal issue, probably is not repairable for a reasonable fee, charging and operation of the battery is an integral part of the motherboard.